# REGEX - Having trouble getting the basics

Tags: c#, regex

I am very new to Regular expression so I apologise for the 'noobyness' of the question...
I need to match a pattern for an ID we use at work.

So far the only specification for the pattern is that it will be 9 characters long, and comprised of Capital letters and digits. The ID can contain 1 or any number of Capital letters or digits, so long as the total length of the string is 9 characters long.

So far i have the following...  [A-Z][0-9]{9}
this does not makes sure the string has atleast one letter or digit (so a 9 character long string would pass)... Alos, Im sure it matched a 9 letter word made of non capitals.

I have done a fair bit of googling, but i have not found anything dumbed down enough for me to understand.

Any help very apppreciated :)

Thanks

EDIT: Just to recap the requirements - The id has to be 9 characters long, no more no less. It will be comprised of capital letters and digits. There can be any amount of either letter or digit, so long as the id contains atleast one of each (so BH98T6YUO or R3DBLUEEE or 1234R6789

I will also post my code to make sure that bits not wrong... ??

```
 string myRegex = "A ton of different combinations that i have tried";
 Regex re = new Regex(myRegex);

        // stringCombos is a List<string> containing all my strings
        // The strings contain within them, my id
        // I am attempting to pull out this id 
        // the below is just to print out all found matches for each string in the list 
        foreach (string s in stringCombos)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(s);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
            Console.Write(s);
            Console.WriteLine("  ---  was split into the following:");
            foreach (Match mt in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mt.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Im sure it matched a 9 letter word made of non capitals* Make sure you're using a case sensitive searching mode.

Comment: "contain 1 or any number of Capital letters or digits" and "the total length of the string is 9 characters long" sounds a bit contradictory. Is this variable length or fixed length?

Comment: your pattern actually matches a single capital letter followed by 9 digits...

Comment: Is that must match 9 characters either uppercase or numeric.  Or 9 characters upper or numeric with atleast one of them uppercase?

Comment: @BobVale it is 9 characters that are a mix of Capital letters and digits... (have just added an edit to make it clearer)

Comment: @Jammerz858 you've updated the question to answer my comment, see my updated answer

Comment: @Jammerz858 My answer has been updated to accomodate your new requirement of matching where the ID is within the string rather than the string is exactly the ID

Comment: @Jammerz858 you've missed in your specification what to do if the input string is exactly `12345678AB`.  Should the result return two answers of `12345678A` and `23456789AB` or should that be a fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have to learn regular expressions as a language. The curve is kind of steep, but there are a ton of excellent tutorials for the basics. Also, you might *get* this in a chat situation (SO has a chat functionality) - that is how I originally learnt them...

I think this might work for your case:

```
[A-Z0-9]{1,9}
```

According to your update, for exactly 9 elements, use:

```
[A-Z0-9]{9}
```

Note, though, that the requirement to include at least one letter and at least one digit is not expressed in this solution. An easy way to do that would be to apply a second and third match to the first one:

```
[0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*
[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z]*
```

Thereby matching three times. You might be able to get this result with the fancy forward and backward reference stuff, but you cannot really capture that requirement with a [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, once I changed the last bit to {9} it worked perfectly! Apologies for the original loose specifcation on the id's requirements, I have editted to hopefully show these more clearly. Thanks again :D

Comment: But this will also match the string "12345678AB" and find the ID "12345678A" and the ID "2345678AB", is this really the requirement?

Comment: @BobVale, well spotted! Thank you! I updated my answer to reflect that!

Comment: @DarenThomas How does that change fix the issue in my previous comment?

Comment: @BobVale, as I understood it, the requirement was: id is nine characters long, comprized of capitals letters and digits (first regex) and at least one letter (second regex) and at liest one digit (third regex). I had made a mistake in my first draft of regexes 2 and 3. Now, when I reread your comment, I see what you mean. Right. OP has to figure out boundaries too. Oh dear. A problem well stated is half solved...

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the start and then end of the string using ^ and $, this means that it will match 9 characters and not 10

```
^[0-9A-Z]$
```

You aren't exact clear on the requirements the above match will match 9 characters either capital or numeric.

You may find [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) useful for trying out your expressions.

EDIT (With new requirements) if you are requiring a minimum of 1 Uppercase character you could use the following.

```
\b[0-9A-Z]{8}(?:(?<=.*[A-Z].*)[0-9]|(?<=.*[0-9].*)[A-Z])\b
```

Breakdown

`\b` Match a word boundry

`[0-9A-Z]{8}` 8 Chars that are either uppercase or numbers

`(?:` Begins a non capturing group, this is to enclose the or condition

`(?<=.*[A-Z].*)[0-9]` This basically matches [0-9] aslong as there is an A-Z somewhere before it in the first `[0-9A-Z]{8}` capture

`|` OR

`(?<=.*[0-9].*)[A-Z]` This basically matches [A-Z] aslong as there is an 0-9 somewhere before it in the first `[0-9A-Z]{8}` capture

`)` close non capturing group

`\b` match a word boundry

Basically do a match on the first 8 chars and then if the 9th char is a digit then there has to be an uppercase in the first 8, if the 9th is an A-Z then there has to be a digit in the first 8

The new edited version will now find ID's that appear within the string rather than requiring the string exactly match them.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation of the above expressions has cleared  a few things up for me... But, sadly it does not return any results :( I have editted my question to hopefully cast a bit more light on my requirements and posted as much code as I can. Unfortunately, I cannot post the strings from which i am retireving the match.

Comment: @Jammerz858, this is because your actual code shows that you are trying to match where the ID is contain within the string rather than does the string match the criteria. Can you confirm that there will definitely be word seperators around your matches.